# make array property to have index as namespace

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have problem making a new array of object. I want to transform this

```
[{
  a: 1,
  b: true
},{
  a: 2,
  b: false
}]
```

to

```
[{
  a_1: 1
},{
  a_2: 2
}]
```

I tried map

```
const result = a.map((o, i) => {
      let row = []
      i = ++i
        row = {
          [`a_${i}`]: o.a,
          [`b_${i}`]: b.a
        }
      return row
    })
```

but it returned this

```
[
  {
    "a_1": 1,
    "b_1": true
  },
  {
    "a_2": 2,
    "b_2": false
  }
]
```

How do I get this

```
[
  {
    "a_1": 1,
  },{
    "b_1": true
},{
    "a_2": 2,
},
  {
    "b_2": false
  }
]
```

I can flatten it but the property key has dynamic index, imagine it's not small size like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` and `Object.entries` and `flat`

```js
let arr = [{ a: 1, b: true }, { a: 2, b: false}]

const result = arr.map((o, i) => {
  return Object.entries(o).map(([key, value]) => ({
    [key + '_' + (i + 1)]: value
  }))
}).flat()

console.log(result)
```

---

Also you can use `Array.flatMap`

```js
let arr = [{ a: 1, b: true }, { a: 2, b: false}]

const result = arr.flatMap((o, i) => {
  return Object.entries(o).map(([key, value]) => ({
    [key + '_' + (i + 1)]: value
  }))
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You can use [`Array.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead of mapping then flattening the result.

Answer (score 1):

And you can use `reduce`:

```js
let arr = [{a: 1,b: true},{a: 2,b: false}];

let brr= arr.reduce((acc,e, i)=>{
 Object.entries(e).map(([key,value])=>{
   acc.push({[`${key}_${i+1}`]:value})
 });
 return acc
},[])

console.log(brr)
```